# Can I get a refund from the Canadian consulate if my transit visa didn't arrive in time for my trip?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, refunds

I applied for a transit visa on the Embassy of Canada web site on 19 June 17. On 12 July 17, I was told to take my passport to the Embassy's Spanish location. I left my passport there and sent an email asking when my it would be returned to me. I needed to know whether or not to cancel my flight, scheduled for 21 July 17 at 7 am. I didn't get a response, but staff at the Embassy told me that I would get my passport and visa in time.

On 20 July 17, I was told that I would receive my passport and visa on 21 July 17 at 16:00 hrs. I had no time to cancel the flight; I lost the money for that and what I paid for the visa (almost €70). Now, I've bought another ticket but it will not take me through Canada.

In this situation, can I apply for a refund from the Canadian Embassy?

Comment: You can always ask, but they will probably refuse.  Your best bet is travel insurance, if you have it.

Comment: 99% no because they issued the Visa you paid for.  They're not interested in whether or not you can actually use it.

Comment: Aren't Canadian transit Visas free? Who did you pay 70 euro to?

Comment: @phoog It is very questionable whether the commercial insurance covers the costs paid to a government authority.

Comment: @Shuangistan I was thinking more of the airfare for the original ticket.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

The conditions under which one can receive a visa refund from the Canadian government are quite limited.  [They are listed by Citizenship and Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/fees/refunds/when.asp), and do not apply even remotely to your circumstances.  It would be a waste of your time to write to your nearest Canadian embassy asking for a refund; they simply will not grant it.